# Python 3 - Convert multiple datetime string formats into one format in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am having a trouble converting my datetime string column which contains different formats into one format. Here's the example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(['2/5/18 21:24', '22/8/17 13:18', '23/8/17 10:47', '2018-09-02 10:15:25'], columns=["date_time"])
# '2018-09-02 10:15:25' this is not September, but should be February
```

If it's only converting from 1 format to another, for example, `2/5/18 21:24` to `2018-02-05 21:24:00` then I know how to do it.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2/5/18 21:24', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%h %H:%M:%S')
```

Initially, I thought there were only 2 different date formats: `%m/%d/%y %H:%M` and `%Y-%m-%h %H:%M:%S` so I thought I could do something like:

```
test['converted_date_time'] = np.where(test['date_time'].str.contains(r'/'), datetime.datetime.strptime(str(test['date_time']), '%m/%d/%y %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%h %H:%M:%S'), test['date_time'])
```

But as you can see it wouldn't work and thus, I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/usr1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Users/usr1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '0     2/5/18 21:24\n1    22/8/17 13:18\n2    23/8/17 10:47\n3     2018-09-02 10:15:25\nName: date_time, dtype: object' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'
```

Additionally, I have also tried using `dateutil` module:

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse(str(test['date_time']))
```

and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/usr1/ht_monitoring/venv_ht_monitoring/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1182, in parse
return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/usr1/ht_monitoring/venv_ht_monitoring/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 559, in parse
raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

My python version is

```
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc. |Pycharm 2017.3.2 (Community Edition)
MacOS High Sierra version 10.13.3
```

Could someone please help with solving this issue so I can convert all dates to this format `%Y-%m-%h %H:%M:%S`? Thank you in advance!

Edit update:
    data was extracted from hundreds of files with filename format = filename_yyyy-mm-dd.csv

Comment: How did you get these inconsistent date formats? From a file? I would try and solve the problem at the source, by changing the dates in the file. Which may require having a script going through each line and updating it as necessary.

Comment: Aside: to my knowledge, the format year-day-month (2018-09-02 as Feb 9) doesn't even exist. It makes me wonder how that came about in your dataset.

Comment: @Evert it did come from different files which are about hundreds of them and I am not sure how these different date formats were generated in the first place. As for now it's not worth going back and fix them all. I am just wondering if it's possible to fix these and focus on ensuring the future files don't have this problem.

Comment: What about creating a function that handles all format cases in an if-elif-...-else chain, formatting each possible string to a datetime object, then running df['date'].apply(<conversion-function>)? I don't know how many rows you have to convert, but this seems to be the most direct and failproof way. You'll just have to make sure you filter the special cases first, so you end up with the more general cases at the end of the if-chain.

Comment: @Evert due to time constraint, I ended up extracting the dates from the file name instead, however I'll lose the exact datetime for each entry in the file. I might create a function in the future to do this if I still need it. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: The filename? Where in your question do you mention the filename?

Comment: i just added it above. I did not want to go down this road which is why I did not include this info in the first place. @Evert